# How to display a node as multi-step?

Tags: forms

I have installed Multistep module and it worked well for forms (e.g. save node, edit node). But when I switched to "Manage Display" tab and add "Multistep Form" group, it didn't work. No multistep form block appeared in Structure->Block for displaying a node.

I have also tried "Div" for displaying field group, but it's just a collapsible box.

Is it possible to display node as multi-step?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use node as multi step form with help of  **page break field  Module** . Enabled it and make it as one of the field where want in the node